# what's the meaning of android:orderInCategory?

Tags: android, menuitem

In menu item I found this the tag

`android:orderInCategory="100"`
.

What is the work of this tag?

And what will happen if I change `100` to other?

Comment: it's the order of items...you can change it to anything...but what matters is order....an item with "150" or "200" will come after "50" or "100"

Comment: they use "100" as starting value and "200" as 2nd value...so that if a new value need to be inserted in between, it is easier to choose the new order value "150" and other values needn't be changed

Comment: @M D 
I changed some value but no change found!

Comment: I used 3 menu but use the same `100` but everything is working.

Comment: i used 200 for that 3 vertical dots to always place at the end. thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`android:orderInCategory="Integer"`

Use in two way

1>....Action bar menu items will appear from left to right in Action Bar depending on the ascending order.

2>....For overflow menu items will be displayed from top to bottom depending upon the ascending order you have specified.